# EJS to assign variables?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am attempting to assign a variable with EJS.

```
<% var career14 = <%= currentUser.career14.name %> %>
```

This gives me the following error: Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".

**Question: What is the correct way to assign a variable with EJS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS expects that when you open a tag, you use only another tag for closing, you cant use other tags inside.

In your situation, delete the inner tags and it should work.

```
<% var career14 = currentUser.career14.name %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!